# R: What is meant by "inbag" risk and "oobag" risk in mboost?

Tags: r, machine-learning

```
library(mboost)
help(boost_control)
```

In the documentation for `boost_control`, which has the following syntax:

```
boost_control(mstop = 100, nu = 0.1,
              risk = c("inbag", "oobag", "none"), stopintern = FALSE,
              center = TRUE, trace = FALSE)
```

the `risk` parameter has several options (`inbag, oobag, none`). The description is as follows:

> a character indicating how the empirical risk should be computed for
> each boosting iteration. inbag leads to risks computed for the
> learning sample (i.e., all non-zero weights), oobag to risks based on
> the out-of-bag (all observations with zero weights) and none to no
> risk computations at all.

I am not quite sure what is meant by "inbag" vs "out-of-bag." Is this function bagging the data (1 bag for training, 1 for testing) and then fitting a model on the training bag? Then the `inbag` risk is the error of the model fit onto the training bag. And `out-of-bag` risk is the error of the model fit onto the test bag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally an R regression 'control' list defaults to the first item in the parameter character vector (which looking at the Usage section of the help page is "inbag"). So if you did offer a "control" parameter list or if you specified the control parameters without a value for the `risk`-value, you would be telling the program to use "inbag". If you wanted to change that to out-of-bag risk then you would give the `control` parameter in the main regression function a list value such as:

```
  ...., control =list(risk="oobag", ...) ,  # other named control parameters in ...
```

Or perhaps:

```
   ...., control = boost_control(risk="oobag", ...)
```

(I'm not sure of the exact syntax but that's what manuals are for.)

Bagging methods typically work on small randomly drawn subsets of data with the items used in these subsets typically marked as "in-bag" and the rest being used for verification or validation purposes. There is an iterative process of correcting estimates until some limit is reached, perhaps set by the `mstop` parameter in this case. The "risk" being measured is the departure of prediction from the measured outcomes of the cases. So you could use either the inbag set or the out-of-bag set for the iterative scoring and adjustment of the model parameter estimates.

I wondered if I could refer you to the vignette referenced by the help pages of the `mboost` package but it doesn't have a single hit to a search for "bag". (R code to bring up a slightly modified version of the paper that is used as the literature support which is otherwise behind a paywall in its original version.))

```
 vignette(package = "mboost", "mboost_tutorial")
```

Comment: I'm still confused by the difference  between "inbag" and "oobag." So bagging randomly draws data and divides them into 2 sets: training and validation. A model is trained on the training set. For "inbag," is the model being validated on the training set? And is "oobag" validating the model on the validation set?

Comment: It's more complicated than that. A small subset is selected and used to make an iterative modification to the model parameters. This happens over and over. The items that are not selected are used to validate the interim versions of the model (or more accurately the model sequence).